# Javascript - Adding a remove option to a image preview

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a multiple images uploader preview with a delete button for the previewed images. Those deleted images should not be submitted to the server. Most of the solutions here and on Internet use jquery, which I want to avoid. It would be nice to have a vanilla javascript solution here. so, my question is:

How can I add a remove option(link) to the preview images?

```js
 const input = document.querySelector('input');
    const preview = document.querySelector('.preview');

    input.style.opacity = 0;

    input.addEventListener('change', updateImageDisplay);

    function updateImageDisplay() {
      while(preview.firstChild) {
        preview.removeChild(preview.firstChild);
      }

      const curFiles = input.files;
      if(curFiles.length === 0) {
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        para.textContent = 'No files currently selected for upload';
        preview.appendChild(para);
      } else {
        const list = document.createElement('ol');
        preview.appendChild(list);

        for(const file of curFiles) {
          const listItem = document.createElement('li');
          const para = document.createElement('p');

          if(validFileType(file)) {
            para.textContent = `File name ${file.name}, file size ${returnFileSize(file.size)}.`;
            const image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            listItem.appendChild(image);
            listItem.appendChild(para);
          } else {
            para.textContent = `File name ${file.name}: Not a valid file type. Update your selection.`;
            listItem.appendChild(para);
          }

          list.appendChild(listItem);
        }
      }
    }

 const fileTypes = [
        'image/apng',
        'image/bmp',
        'image/gif',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/svg+xml',
        'image/tiff',
        'image/webp',
        `image/x-icon`
    ];

    function validFileType(file) {
      return fileTypes.includes(file.type);
    }

    function returnFileSize(number) {
      if(number < 1024) {
        return number + 'bytes';
      } else if(number > 1024 && number < 1048576) {
        return (number/1024).toFixed(1) + 'KB';
      } else if(number > 1048576) {
        return (number/1048576).toFixed(1) + 'MB';
      }
    }
```

```css
    form {
      width: 600px;
      background: #ccc;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    form ol {
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    form li, div > p {
      background: #eee;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      list-style-type: none;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    form img {
      height: 64px;
      order: 1;
    }

    form p {
      line-height: 32px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    form label, form button {
      background-color: #7F9CCB;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px ridge black;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      height: auto;
    }

    form label:hover, form button:hover {
      background-color: #2D5BA3;
      color: white;
    }

    form label:active, form button:active {
      background-color: #0D3F8F;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
      <label for="image_uploads">Choose images to upload (PNG, JPG)</label>
      <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="image_uploads" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
      <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: There are 2 answers in the question. Which answer are you referring to? Please add your code, the issue you are facing and all the necessary details in the question. If that answer is deleted, this question will have no future value

Comment: Added code and clarity to the question.

Comment: No JQuery. Vanilla javascript

Comment: It looks like you're asking folks to do your whole job for you. The task seems straightforward. Have you actually tried doing it yourself? What isn't working? Does the link not get created? Does it not appear? Do you not know how to programmatically create a clickable thing? Do you need help breaking down the feature into basic parts?